# How to read/view a .x file

Tags: c++

Some .x files when opened with something like wordpad have readable material. You can look at the vertices and all that and can even edit it. But some are just symbols which are not readable. My question is: Is there a way to be able to read the information?

What I am trying to do is change the texture path name. The name that the .x file tells directx to go to to load a texture from file. What happens is I downloaded an .x file and the textures are not being loaded because the pathname for the textures is the pathname that whoever created the file used. And obviously I need to change it to where I have the textures now. Or I would have to create folders that match the pathname of every .x file I use which would just be silly.

Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try using a hex editor to look inside - here's an online one that doesn't need any installation https://hexed.it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below should work, here is the full file and headers as well as other utility files to parse X files using C++: https://github.com/assimp/assimp/tree/master/code and https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/code/XFileParser.cpp

```
#ifndef ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_X_IMPORTER

#include "XFileParser.h"
#include "XFileHelper.h"
#include "fast_atof.h"
#include "Exceptional.h"
#include "TinyFormatter.h"
#include "ByteSwapper.h"
#include "StringUtils.h"
#include <assimp/DefaultLogger.hpp>


using namespace Assimp;
using namespace Assimp::XFile;
using namespace Assimp::Formatter;

#ifndef ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_COMPRESSED_X

#   ifdef ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_OWN_ZLIB
#       include <zlib.h>
#   else
#       include "../contrib/zlib/zlib.h"
#   endif

// Magic identifier for MSZIP compressed data
#define MSZIP_MAGIC 0x4B43
#define MSZIP_BLOCK 32786

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Dummy memory wrappers for use with zlib
static void* dummy_alloc (void* /*opaque*/, unsigned int items, unsigned int size)  {
    return ::operator new(items*size);
}

static void  dummy_free  (void* /*opaque*/, void* address)  {
    return ::operator delete(address);
}

#endif // !! ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_COMPRESSED_X

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Constructor. Creates a data structure out of the XFile given in the memory block.
XFileParser::XFileParser( const std::vector<char>& pBuffer)
{
    mMajorVersion = mMinorVersion = 0;
    mIsBinaryFormat = false;
    mBinaryNumCount = 0;
    P = End = NULL;
    mLineNumber = 0;
    mScene = NULL;

    // vector to store uncompressed file for INFLATE'd X files
    std::vector<char> uncompressed;

    // set up memory pointers
    P = &pBuffer.front();
    End = P + pBuffer.size() - 1;

    // check header
    if( strncmp( P, "xof ", 4) != 0)
        throw DeadlyImportError( "Header mismatch, file is not an XFile.");

    // read version. It comes in a four byte format such as "0302"
    mMajorVersion = (unsigned int)(P[4] - 48) * 10 + (unsigned int)(P[5] - 48);
    mMinorVersion = (unsigned int)(P[6] - 48) * 10 + (unsigned int)(P[7] - 48);

    bool compressed = false;

    // txt - pure ASCII text format
    if( strncmp( P + 8, "txt ", 4) == 0)
        mIsBinaryFormat = false;

    // bin - Binary format
    else if( strncmp( P + 8, "bin ", 4) == 0)
        mIsBinaryFormat = true;

    // tzip - Inflate compressed text format
    else if( strncmp( P + 8, "tzip", 4) == 0)
    {
        mIsBinaryFormat = false;
        compressed = true;
    }
    // bzip - Inflate compressed binary format
    else if( strncmp( P + 8, "bzip", 4) == 0)
    {
        mIsBinaryFormat = true;
        compressed = true;
    }
    else ThrowException( format() << "Unsupported xfile format '" <<
       P[8] << P[9] << P[10] << P[11] << "'");

    // float size
    mBinaryFloatSize = (unsigned int)(P[12] - 48) * 1000
        + (unsigned int)(P[13] - 48) * 100
        + (unsigned int)(P[14] - 48) * 10
        + (unsigned int)(P[15] - 48);

    if( mBinaryFloatSize != 32 && mBinaryFloatSize != 64)
        ThrowException( format() << "Unknown float size " << mBinaryFloatSize << " specified in xfile header." );

    // The x format specifies size in bits, but we work in bytes
    mBinaryFloatSize /= 8;

    P += 16;

    // If this is a compressed X file, apply the inflate algorithm to it
    if (compressed)
    {
#ifdef ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_COMPRESSED_X
        throw DeadlyImportError("Assimp was built without compressed X support");
#else
        /* ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         * COMPRESSED X FILE FORMAT
         * ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         *    [xhead]
         *    2 major
         *    2 minor
         *    4 type    // bzip,tzip
         *    [mszip_master_head]
         *    4 unkn    // checksum?
         *    2 unkn    // flags? (seems to be constant)
         *    [mszip_head]
         *    2 ofs     // offset to next section
         *    2 magic   // 'CK'
         *    ... ofs bytes of data
         *    ... next mszip_head
         *
         *  http://www.kdedevelopers.org/node/3181 has been very helpful.
         * ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         */

        // build a zlib stream
        z_stream stream;
        stream.opaque = NULL;
        stream.zalloc = &dummy_alloc;
        stream.zfree  = &dummy_free;
        stream.data_type = (mIsBinaryFormat ? Z_BINARY : Z_ASCII);

        // initialize the inflation algorithm
        ::inflateInit2(&stream, -MAX_WBITS);

        // skip unknown data (checksum, flags?)
        P += 6;

        // First find out how much storage we'll need. Count sections.
        const char* P1       = P;
        unsigned int est_out = 0;

        while (P1 + 3 < End)
        {
            // read next offset
            uint16_t ofs = *((uint16_t*)P1);
            AI_SWAP2(ofs); P1 += 2;

            if (ofs >= MSZIP_BLOCK)
                throw DeadlyImportError("X: Invalid offset to next MSZIP compressed block");

            // check magic word
            uint16_t magic = *((uint16_t*)P1);
            AI_SWAP2(magic); P1 += 2;

            if (magic != MSZIP_MAGIC)
                throw DeadlyImportError("X: Unsupported compressed format, expected MSZIP header");

            // and advance to the next offset
            P1 += ofs;
            est_out += MSZIP_BLOCK; // one decompressed block is 32786 in size
        }

        // Allocate storage and terminating zero and do the actual uncompressing
        uncompressed.resize(est_out + 1);
        char* out = &uncompressed.front();
        while (P + 3 < End)
        {
            uint16_t ofs = *((uint16_t*)P);
            AI_SWAP2(ofs);
            P += 4;

            if (P + ofs > End + 2) {
                throw DeadlyImportError("X: Unexpected EOF in compressed chunk");
            }

            // push data to the stream
            stream.next_in   = (Bytef*)P;
            stream.avail_in  = ofs;
            stream.next_out  = (Bytef*)out;
            stream.avail_out = MSZIP_BLOCK;

            // and decompress the data ....
            int ret = ::inflate( &stream, Z_SYNC_FLUSH );
            if (ret != Z_OK && ret != Z_STREAM_END)
                throw DeadlyImportError("X: Failed to decompress MSZIP-compressed data");

            ::inflateReset( &stream );
            ::inflateSetDictionary( &stream, (const Bytef*)out , MSZIP_BLOCK - stream.avail_out );

            // and advance to the next offset
            out +=  MSZIP_BLOCK - stream.avail_out;
            P   += ofs;
        }

        // terminate zlib
        ::inflateEnd(&stream);

        // ok, update pointers to point to the uncompressed file data
        P = &uncompressed[0];
        End = out;

        // FIXME: we don't need the compressed data anymore, could release
        // it already for better memory usage. Consider breaking const-co.
        DefaultLogger::get()->info("Successfully decompressed MSZIP-compressed file");
#endif // !! ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_COMPRESSED_X
    }
    else
    {
        // start reading here
        ReadUntilEndOfLine();
    }

    mScene = new Scene;
    ParseFile();

    // filter the imported hierarchy for some degenerated cases
    if( mScene->mRootNode) {
        FilterHierarchy( mScene->mRootNode);
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Destructor. Destroys all imported data along with it
XFileParser::~XFileParser()
{
    // kill everything we created
    delete mScene;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XFileParser::ParseFile()
{
    bool running = true;
    while( running )
    {
        // read name of next object
        std::string objectName = GetNextToken();
        if (objectName.length() == 0)
            break;

        // parse specific object
        if( objectName == "template")
            ParseDataObjectTemplate();
        else
        if( objectName == "Frame")
            ParseDataObjectFrame( NULL);
        else
        if( objectName == "Mesh")
        {
            // some meshes have no frames at all
            Mesh* mesh = new Mesh;
            ParseDataObjectMesh( mesh);
            mScene->mGlobalMeshes.push_back( mesh);
        } else
        if( objectName == "AnimTicksPerSecond")
            ParseDataObjectAnimTicksPerSecond();
        else
        if( objectName == "AnimationSet")
            ParseDataObjectAnimationSet();
        else
        if( objectName == "Material")
        {
            // Material outside of a mesh or node
            Material material;
            ParseDataObjectMaterial( &material);
            mScene->mGlobalMaterials.push_back( material);
        } else
        if( objectName == "}")
        {
            // whatever?
            DefaultLogger::get()->warn("} found in dataObject");
        } else
        {
            // unknown format
            DefaultLogger::get()->warn("Unknown data object in animation of .x file");
            ParseUnknownDataObject();
        }
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XFileParser::ParseDataObjectTemplate()
{
    // parse a template data object. Currently not stored.
    std::string name;
    readHeadOfDataObject( &name);

    // read GUID
    std::string guid = GetNextToken();

    // read and ignore data members
    bool running = true;
    while ( running )
    {
        std::string s = GetNextToken();

        if( s == "}")
            break;

        if( s.length() == 0)
            ThrowException( "Unexpected end of file reached while parsing template definition");
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XFileParser::ParseDataObjectFrame( Node* pParent)
{
    // A coordinate frame, or "frame of reference." The Frame template
    // is open and can contain any object. The Direct3D extensions (D3DX)
    // mesh-loading functions recognize Mesh, FrameTransformMatrix, and
    // Frame template instances as child objects when loading a Frame
    // instance.
    std::string name;
    readHeadOfDataObject(&name);

    // create a named node and place it at its parent, if given
    Node* node = new Node( pParent);
    node->mName = name;
    if( pParent)
    {
        pParent->mChildren.push_back( node);
    } else
    {
        // there might be multiple root nodes
        if( mScene->mRootNode != NULL)
        {
            // place a dummy root if not there
            if( mScene->mRootNode->mName != "$dummy_root")
            {
                Node* exroot = mScene->mRootNode;
                mScene->mRootNode = new Node( NULL);
                mScene->mRootNode->mName = "$dummy_root";
                mScene->mRootNode->mChildren.push_back( exroot);
                exroot->mParent = mScene->mRootNode;
            }
            // put the new node as its child instead
            mScene->mRootNode->mChildren.push_back( node);
            node->mParent = mScene->mRootNode;
        } else
        {
            // it's the first node imported. place it as root
            mScene->mRootNode = node;
        }
    }

    // Now inside a frame.
    // read tokens until closing brace is reached.
    bool running = true;
    while ( running )
    {
        std::string objectName = GetNextToken();
        if (objectName.size() == 0)
            ThrowException( "Unexpected end of file reached while parsing frame");

        if( objectName == "}")
            break; // frame finished
        else
        if( objectName == "Frame")
            ParseDataObjectFrame( node); // child frame
        else
        if( objectName == "FrameTransformMatrix")
            ParseDataObjectTransformationMatrix( node->mTrafoMatrix);
        else
        if( objectName == "Mesh")
        {
            Mesh* mesh = new Mesh(name);
            node->mMeshes.push_back( mesh);
            ParseDataObjectMesh( mesh);
        } else
        {
            DefaultLogger::get()->warn("Unknown data object in frame in x file");
            ParseUnknownDataObject();
        }
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XFileParser::ParseDataObjectTransformationMatrix( aiMatrix4x4& pMatrix)
{
    // read header, we're not interested if it has a name
    readHeadOfDataObject();

    // read its components
    pMatrix.a1 = ReadFloat(); pMatrix.b1 = ReadFloat();
    pMatrix.c1 = ReadFloat(); pMatrix.d1 = ReadFloat();
    pMatrix.a2 = ReadFloat(); pMatrix.b2 = ReadFloat();
    pMatrix.c2 = ReadFloat(); pMatrix.d2 = ReadFloat();
    pMatrix.a3 = ReadFloat(); pMatrix.b3 = ReadFloat();
    pMatrix.c3 = ReadFloat(); pMatrix.d3 = ReadFloat();
    pMatrix.a4 = ReadFloat(); pMatrix.b4 = ReadFloat();
    pMatrix.c4 = ReadFloat(); pMatrix.d4 = ReadFloat();

    // trailing symbols
    CheckForSemicolon();
    CheckForClosingBrace();
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XFileParser::ParseDataObjectMesh( Mesh* pMesh)
{
    std::string name;
    readHeadOfDataObject( &name);

    // read vertex count
    unsigned int numVertices = ReadInt();
    pMesh->mPositions.resize( numVertices);

    // read vertices
    for( unsigned int a = 0; a < numVertices; a++)
        pMesh->mPositions[a] = ReadVector3();

    // read position faces
    unsigned int numPosFaces = ReadInt();
    pMesh->mPosFaces.resize( numPosFaces);
    for( unsigned int a = 0; a < numPosFaces; a++)
    {
        // read indices
        unsigned int numIndices = ReadInt();
        Face& face = pMesh->mPosFaces[a];
        for (unsigned int b = 0; b < numIndices; b++) {
            face.mIndices.push_back( ReadInt() );
        }
        TestForSeparator();
    }

    // here, other data objects may follow
    bool running = true;
    while ( running )
    {
        std::string objectName = GetNextToken();

        if( objectName.size() == 0)
            ThrowException( "Unexpected end of file while parsing mesh structure");
        else
        if( objectName == "}")
            break; // mesh finished
        else
        if( objectName == "MeshNormals")
            ParseDataObjectMeshNormals( pMesh);
        else
        if( objectName == "MeshTextureCoords")
            ParseDataObjectMeshTextureCoords( pMesh);
        else
        if( objectName == "MeshVertexColors")
            ParseDataObjectMeshVertexColors( pMesh);
        else
        if( objectName == "MeshMaterialList")
            ParseDataObjectMeshMaterialList( pMesh);
        else
        if( objectName == "VertexDuplicationIndices")
            ParseUnknownDataObject(); // we'll ignore vertex duplication indices
        else
        if( objectName == "XSkinMeshHeader")
            ParseDataObjectSkinMeshHeader( pMesh);
        else
        if( objectName == "SkinWeights")
            ParseDataObjectSkinWeights( pMesh);
        else
        {
            DefaultLogger::get()->warn("Unknown data object in mesh in x file");
            ParseUnknownDataObject();
        }
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XFileParser::ParseDataObjectSkinWeights( Mesh *pMesh)
{
    readHeadOfDataObject();

    std::string transformNodeName;
    GetNextTokenAsString( transformNodeName);

    pMesh->mBones.push_back( Bone());
    Bone& bone = pMesh->mBones.back();
    bone.mName = transformNodeName;

    // read vertex weights
    unsigned int numWeights = ReadInt();
    bone.mWeights.reserve( numWeights);

    for( unsigned int a = 0; a < numWeights; a++)
    {
        BoneWeight weight;
        weight.mVertex = ReadInt();
        bone.mWeights.push_back( weight);
    }

    // read vertex weights
    for( unsigned int a = 0; a < numWeights; a++)
        bone.mWeights[a].mWeight = ReadFloat();

    // read matrix offset
    bone.mOffsetMatrix.a1 = ReadFloat(); bone.mOffsetMatrix.b1 = ReadFloat();
    bone.mOffsetMatrix.c1 = ReadFloat(); bone.mOffsetMatrix.d1 = ReadFloat();
    bone.mOffsetMatrix.a2 = ReadFloat(); bone.mOffsetMatrix.b2 = ReadFloat();
    bone.mOffsetMatrix.c2 = ReadFloat(); bone.mOffsetMatrix.d2 = ReadFloat();
    bone.mOffsetMatrix.a3 = ReadFloat(); bone.mOffsetMatrix.b3 = ReadFloat();
    bone.mOffsetMatrix.c3 = ReadFloat(); bone.mOffsetMatrix.d3 = ReadFloat();
    bone.mOffsetMatrix.a4 = ReadFloat(); bone.mOffsetMatrix.b4 = ReadFloat();
    bone.mOffsetMatrix.c4 = ReadFloat(); bone.mOffsetMatrix.d4 = ReadFloat();

    CheckForSemicolon();
    CheckForClosingBrace();
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XFileParser::ParseDataObjectSkinMeshHeader( Mesh* /*pMesh*/ )
{
    readHeadOfDataObject();

    /*unsigned int maxSkinWeightsPerVertex =*/ ReadInt();
    /*unsigned int maxSkinWeightsPerFace =*/ ReadInt();
    /*unsigned int numBonesInMesh = */ReadInt();

    CheckForClosingBrace();
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XFileParser::ParseDataObjectMeshNormals( Mesh* pMesh)
{
    readHeadOfDataObject();

    // read count
    unsigned int numNormals = ReadInt();
    pMesh->mNormals.resize( numNormals);

    // read normal vectors
    for( unsigned int a = 0; a < numNormals; a++)
        pMesh->mNormals[a] = ReadVector3();

    // read normal indices
    unsigned int numFaces = ReadInt();
    if( numFaces != pMesh->mPosFaces.size())
        ThrowException( "Normal face count does not match vertex face count.");

    for( unsigned int a = 0; a < numFaces; a++)
    {
        unsigned int numIndices = ReadInt();
        pMesh->mNormFaces.push_back( Face());
        Face& face = pMesh->mNormFaces.back();

        for( unsigned int b = 0; b < numIndices; b++)
            face.mIndices.push_back( ReadInt());

        TestForSeparator();
    }

    CheckForClosingBrace();
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XFileParser::ParseDataObjectMeshTextureCoords( Mesh* pMesh)
{
    readHeadOfDataObject();
    if( pMesh->mNumTextures + 1 > AI_MAX_NUMBER_OF_TEXTURECOORDS)
        ThrowException( "Too many sets of texture coordinates");

    std::vector<aiVector2D>& coords = pMesh->mTexCoords[pMesh->mNumTextures++];

    unsigned int numCoords = ReadInt();
    if( numCoords != pMesh->mPositions.size())
        ThrowException( "Texture coord count does not match vertex count");

    coords.resize( numCoords);
    for( unsigned int a = 0; a < numCoords; a++)
        coords[a] = ReadVector2();

    CheckForClosingBrace();
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XFileParser::ParseDataObjectMeshVertexColors( Mesh* pMesh)
{
    readHeadOfDataObject();
    if( pMesh->mNumColorSets + 1 > AI_MAX_NUMBER_OF_COLOR_SETS)
        ThrowException( "Too many colorsets");
    std::vector<aiColor4D>& colors = pMesh->mColors[pMesh->mNumColorSets++];

    unsigned int numColors = ReadInt();
    if( numColors != pMesh->mPositions.size())
        ThrowException( "Vertex color count does not match vertex count");

    colors.resize( numColors, aiColor4D( 0, 0, 0, 1));
    for( unsigned int a = 0; a < numColors; a++)
    {
        unsigned int index = ReadInt();
        if( index >= pMesh->mPositions.size())
            ThrowException( "Vertex color index out of bounds");

        colors[index] = ReadRGBA();
        // HACK: (thom) Maxon Cinema XPort plugin puts a third separator here, kwxPort puts a comma.
        // Ignore gracefully.
        if( !mIsBinaryFormat)
        {
            FindNextNoneWhiteSpace();
            if( *P == ';' || *P == ',')
                P++;
        }
    }

    CheckForClosingBrace();
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XFileParser::ParseDataObjectMeshMaterialList( Mesh* pMesh)
{
    readHeadOfDataObject();

    // read material count
    /*unsigned int numMaterials =*/ ReadInt();
    // read non triangulated face material index count
    unsigned int numMatIndices = ReadInt();

    // some models have a material index count of 1... to be able to read them we
    // replicate this single material index on every face
    if( numMatIndices != pMesh->mPosFaces.size() && numMatIndices != 1)
        ThrowException( "Per-Face material index count does not match face count.");

    // read per-face material indices
    for( unsigned int a = 0; a < numMatIndices; a++)
        pMesh->mFaceMaterials.push_back( ReadInt());

    // in version 03.02, the face indices end with two semicolons.
    // commented out version check, as version 03.03 exported from blender also has 2 semicolons
    if( !mIsBinaryFormat) // && MajorVersion == 3 && MinorVersion <= 2)
    {
        if(P < End && *P == ';')
            ++P;
    }

    // if there was only a single material index, replicate it on all faces
    while( pMesh->mFaceMaterials.size() < pMesh->mPosFaces.size())
        pMesh->mFaceMaterials.push_back( pMesh->mFaceMaterials.front());

    // read following data objects
    bool running = true;
    while ( running )
    {
        std::string objectName = GetNextToken();
        if( objectName.size() == 0)
            ThrowException( "Unexpected end of file while parsing mesh material list.");
        else
        if( objectName == "}")
            break; // material list finished
        else
        if( objectName == "{")
        {
            // template materials
            std::string matName = GetNextToken();
            Material material;
            material.mIsReference = true;
            material.mName = matName;
            pMesh->mMaterials.push_back( material);

            CheckForClosingBrace(); // skip }
        } else
        if( objectName == "Material")
        {
            pMesh->mMaterials.push_back( Material());
            ParseDataObjectMaterial( &pMesh->mMaterials.back());
        } else
        if( objectName == ";")
        {
            // ignore
        } else
        {
            DefaultLogger::get()->warn("Unknown data object in material list in x file");
            ParseUnknownDataObject();
        }
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XFileParser::ParseDataObjectMaterial( Material* pMaterial)
{
    std::string matName;
    readHeadOfDataObject( &matName);
    if( matName.empty())
        matName = std::string( "material") + to_string( mLineNumber );
    pMaterial->mName = matName;
    pMaterial->mIsReference = false;

    // read material values
    pMaterial->mDiffuse = ReadRGBA();
    pMaterial->mSpecularExponent = ReadFloat();
    pMaterial->mSpecular = ReadRGB();
    pMaterial->mEmissive = ReadRGB();

    // read other data objects
    bool running = true;
    while ( running )
    {
        std::string objectName = GetNextToken();
        if( objectName.size() == 0)
            ThrowException( "Unexpected end of file while parsing mesh material");
        else
        if( objectName == "}")
            break; // material finished
        else
        if( objectName == "TextureFilename" || objectName == "TextureFileName")
        {
            // some exporters write "TextureFileName" instead.
            std::string texname;
            ParseDataObjectTextureFilename( texname);
            pMaterial->mTextures.push_back( TexEntry( texname));
        } else
        if( objectName == "NormalmapFilename" || objectName == "NormalmapFileName")
        {
            // one exporter writes out the normal map in a separate filename tag
            std::string texname;
            ParseDataObjectTextureFilename( texname);
            pMaterial->mTextures.push_back( TexEntry( texname, true));
        } else
        {
            DefaultLogger::get()->warn("Unknown data object in material in x file");
            ParseUnknownDataObject();
        }
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XFileParser::ParseDataObjectAnimTicksPerSecond()
{
    readHeadOfDataObject();
    mScene->mAnimTicksPerSecond = ReadInt();
    CheckForClosingBrace();
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void XFileParser::ParseDataObjectAnimationSet()
{
    std::string animName;
    readHeadOfDataObject( &animName);

    Animation* anim = new Animation;
    mScene->mAnims.push_back( anim);
    anim->mName = animName;

    bool running = true;
    while ( running )
    {
        std::string objectName = GetNextToken();
        if( objectName.length() == 0)
            ThrowException( "Unexpected end of file while parsing animation set.");
        else
        if( objectName == "}")
            break; // animation set finished
        else
        if( objectName == "Animation")
            ParseDataObjectAnimation( anim);
        else
        {
            DefaultLogger::get()->warn("Unknown data object in animation set in x file");
            ParseUnknownDataObject();
        }
    }
}

[...]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am not looking for a way to load a .x file. I have found something already. This looks interesting though, I will check it out. I want to be able to physically read it, with my eyes.  Some are human readable but some are not and I am looking for a way to read the non readable ones.

Comment: Hey, understood. You can still use that library to import the x file, read it entirely and export it to a human readable format such a JSON.